# Prestashop faceted search displays a long range of values for price

Tags: filter, faceted-search, prestashop-1.7, searchfiltercollection

I am using prestashop1.7 and was trying to edit the faceted search filters. I am not able to configure the price search filter since it displays a long list of values even when I have configured it ( from prestashop backend ) to display only 5 list of values. Is there a way to resolve this. Have provided screenshots also.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XffS.png [ Image of backend where I have set the value to 5 max]
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjO2V.png [ Display of price filter on our website isovi.in]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I found that after more than 6 months is it still the unresolved issue. It is shame for PrestaShop as the product, this is core functionality what was available until version 1.6.

More information You can find on:
http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-2910

Answer (score 0):

While setting up a shop I encountered the same issue with PS 1.7.2.3 and I fixed that: Pull Request https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_facetedsearch/pull/29.

I didn't want to have equal ranges (f.e. 350..350) and stick to the maximum number of allowed ranges (I had the same issue that there were too many ranges).

The modifications of my pull request must be applied by your developer. I'm not sure if my changes will be incorporated as there seems to be a bigger refactoring in progress.

Nevertheless I added my changes as the original code generated essentially useless ranges (my point of view).